# docker-engine to docker-compose to docker compose file relationship

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-engine

Folks:

Thank you in advance for your time and attention.

What is the relationship between docker-compose.yml file and the docker-compose cli executeable is the info that I am trying t?

Here is my example.

```
$>docker-compose version

docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
docker-py version: 1.10.6
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

```
$> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue May 30 18:21:18 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue May 30 18:21:18 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Now the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  database:
    image: "${DOCKER_REPO_NAME}.......
```

Based on the documentation at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file, if the **docker-engine** version is *17.04*, it should support **docker-compose file version** directive *3.2*

However I see this. error

### ***** ERROR follows******

```
$>docker-compose ${NO_ANSI} config -q


ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a version of "2" (or "2.0") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

So the question is what am I doing wrong ?

-Narahari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.9.0 of docker-compose only supports up to version 2.1 of the compose file specification.

See https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-compose/#190-2016-11-16

Answer (score 2):

Your docker-compose is pretty old and just supports up to version 2.1 of docker-compose.yml files.

[Version 2.2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-22) is supported by version 1.13.0 or higher.

You either update docker-compose (recommended) or downgrade the .yml to be v1 or v2.1 compliant.

In the .yml reference guide there is a table with compatibilities notes.

Comment: Hmm.  But version directive of 2.1 works with docker-compose 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

[Docker Compose release 1.9.0...](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.9.0)

> Introduced version 2.1 of the `docker-compose.yml` specification. This
>   version requires to be used with Docker Engine 1.12 or above.

It looks like you need at least [Docker Compose 1.13.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.13.0) to use a compose file with `version: "2.2"`.  (I don't see this clearly documented anywhere other than the individual GitHub release pages though.)